# Keyboard Shortcut for Page Reloading Doesn't work during Video Playback

Tags: google-chrome

I'm playing a video in Chrome, and when I click "Command-R" nothing happens. However, when I click the reload button on my navigation bar, the page reloads no problem.

Why is the keyboard shortcut disabled during video playback and is there a way to change that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for this is that the embedded Flash player has the focus, and receives all keyboard commands. If you click outside the player, then hit Cmd+R, refresh will work as expected.

When the web shifts to HTML 5 video, this problem will disappear! Until then, you'll just have to live with it, I'm afraid.